# Using VueX $store to Vue Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

**Background**

I have created a router/index.js file and created a router for my Vue application. I added VueX to the application and am using it throughout some of the components. I would like to use a getter inside of router to check the permissions of a user logged in but I am having trouble importing VueX correctly.

**Problem**

When I important my store and module to the router file `index.js`, I am trying to use `this.$store.registerModule()`. When I try this I get undefined on `this.$store`.

**Example**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import authentication from '../store/modules/authentication';
import store from '../store';


if (!(store && store.state && store.state[name])) {
  this.$store.registerModule(name, authentication);
}
```

This logic works in any Vue component I use it in but it does not work in the router file.

My goal is to be able to check state in VueX like this,

```
const getters = {
  ...mapGetters('authentication', ['IS_LOGGED_IN'])
};

const router = new Router({
{
      path: '/admin',
      name: 'Admin',
      component: Admin,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        isAdmin: true
      }
  ]
});


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (
    to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth) &&
    to.matched.some(record => record.meta.isAdmin)
  ) {
    if (!getters.IS_LOGGED_IN && !getters.IS_ADMIN) {
      next({
        path: '/login',
        params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath }
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!getters.IS_LOGGED_IN) {
      next({
        path: '/login',
        params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath }
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.guest)) {
    next();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

**Question**

What is the correct way to use VueX with Vue Router?

**Things I tried**

I tried using,

```
store.registerModule(name, authentication);
```

This throws undefined on, `registerModule`

Comment: Omit the `this.` prefix. You have imported your store as `store` so that's what you use

Comment: Thank you but I have tried that. When I try that I get undefined still but on, registerModule

Comment: I updated my question but specifically, `store.registerModule(name, authentication);`

Comment: What does your `../store` script export?

Comment: `Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    authentication
  }
});

export default store;
`

Comment: I am using store in the router without issues. store does not throw undefined. regsiterModule throws undefined and so does store.registerModule  and this.$store or $store also throw undefined.

Comment: What **exactly** is the error message? _"throws undefined"_ is too vague to interpret correctly

Comment: Also, why are you trying to register the authentication module in your router? It looks like you already have it defined in the `modules` key in your store

Comment: the store instance in **router inatance** will be same as the one injected into **Vue instance**, or different?

Comment: I would expect it and want it to be the same. I am just trying to call an action. Store and router are both imported to main.js and passed to new Vue(). I am wondering if them being instantiated up one level in the same file has something to do with not being able to access them here. But even then I do not understand why I can not call registerModule after I import store.

Comment: I think one hacky solution will be like this: in your index.js, you will import router (Vue Router instance) from  `vue-router.js`, then import store (Vuex instance) from `vuex-store.js`, then let `router.$store=store`. inside your router navigation, you can access the store by `this.$store`.

Comment: This should work fine as long as you use the `store.registerModule()` variant and not `this.$store.registerModule()` because router does not get injected with `this.$store`. I use even use an import of `store` in one of my store modules to access other module commits and it works.

Comment: I tested your scenario, used `registerModule` in the router, re-registering an existing module with a new alias, and that also works - if I console log store I can see the 2nd registration in state under it's new alias.

Comment: Therefore, the problem has got to be outside the code you have posted so far. It looks like store is not instantiated properly for some reason. Can you post a full sample app somewhere?

Comment: @RichardMatsen I checked this and when importing store and accessing it like this, store.getters['authentication/IS_ADMIN'] I can get the value in state for that getter. But, I can not use store.registerModule. I would love to see the way you setup the test application you were mentioning. Also, thanks a lot for going back and forth with me on this it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tested on my current development app, but essentially it is Vue CLI with a fairly standard store (although with modules) and also a standard router. Will but together a sandbox tomorrow.